# how do i turn off postfix bounce notice

Tags: postfix, configuration, content-filter

In main.cf currently I have

```
notify_classes = delay, policy, protocol, resource, software
bounce_notice_recipient =
2bounce_notice_recipient =
```

Followed another thread, and it recommends setting bounce to "discard", of which I have done.

```
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       discard
```

I am still getting a notice email to postmaster for each bounced spam.

What else do I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

In main.cf set `notify_classes=bounce` and `bounce_notice_recipient=postmaster` (which should be the default. And then postmaster gets the copies of every bounce message.

You MUST NOT disable bounces. They are needed to notify the sender! And as there has to be a sender for a mail, this particular sender will be informed.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Postfix master.cf file and find the following line:

```
bounce unix - - n - 0 bounce
```

Change it to this:

```
bounce unix - - n - 0 discard
```

**Next, restart Postfix.**

Please be advised that you will see an error in your logs whenever Postfix runs the discard handler instead of the bounce handler. The errors will look similar to this:

```
Dec 15 16:07:40 websrv1 postfix/discard[15220]: warning: unexpected attribute nrequest from bounce socket (expecting: flags)

Dec 15 16:07:40 websrv1 postfix/discard[15220]: warning: deliver_request_get: error receiving common attributes
```